# How to pop up 'alert' message from controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to pop up a message from controller to view. But not hardcoded message, I want to pop up a string. Here what I did in my controller:

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Hardcode message');</script>");
```

The above code is working fine, but if I put some string in message like alert('"+someString+"'); Its not showing anything. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does someString contain a `'`?

Comment: Why using `Response.Write`? Just use `ViewBag` in controller side e.g. `ViewBag.Message = "something"` and write something like this inside `script` tag: `alert('@ViewBag.Message')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add also your js script to View file. I think it is better way then direct writing to Response.

So add to your model property containing js script which you want to render and then use it in your view file:

```
<script>
   @Model.MyScriptToRun
</script>
```

btw. it is not better idea to extract your js to another file and then include it to your view ?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/yourJs.js")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for providing an answer to this question. Please could you add relevant code to your answer. Links tend to break over time, and somebody viewing this question in a couple of years may find your link has become broken, which would devalue your answer.